# Python multiprocessing - check status of each processes

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I wonder if it is possible to check how long of each processes take.
for example, there are four workers and the job should take no more than 10 seconds, but one of worker take more than 10 seconds.Is there way to raise a alert after 10 seconds and before process finish the job. 
My initial thought is using manager, but it seems I have wait till process finished.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found this solution time ago (somewhere here in StackOverflow) and I am very happy with it.

Basically, it uses [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) to raise an exception if a process takes more than expected.

All you need to do is to add this two classes to your code:

```
import signal


class TimeoutError(Exception):
    """Custom error for Timeout class."""
    pass


class Timeout:
    """A timeout handler with context manager based on UNIX signals."""

    def __init__(self, seconds=1, error_message='TimeoutError'):
        self.seconds = seconds
        self.error_message = error_message

    def handle_timeout(self, signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutError(self.error_message)

    def __enter__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.handle_timeout)
        signal.alarm(self.seconds)

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        signal.alarm(0)
```

Here is a general example of how it works:

```
import time

with Timeout(seconds=3, error_message='JobX took too much time'):
    try:
        time.sleep(10) #your job
    except TimeoutError as e:
        print(e)
```

In your case, I would add the with statement to the job that your worker need to perform. Then you catch the Exception and you do what you think is best.

Alternatively, you can periodically check if a process is alive:

```
timeout = 3 #seconds 
start = time.time()
while time.time() - start < timeout:
    if any(proces.is_alive() for proces in processes):
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print('All processes done')
else:
    print("Timeout!")
    # do something
```

Comment: It seems to me your context management function will change worker function.It is good, but my expectation is not touching worker function.

Comment: It doesn't change the worker function in term of what it does, although you need to indent the worker function under the with statement. I don't see any particular problem in doing so, maybe in your case is different, if you publish your actual function I can try to make a working implementation of it using `with timeout`.

Comment: Sadly, this does not work on windows as there is no SIGALRM

Comment: @julaine check this for a windows-compatible solution https://9to5answer.com/python-windows-equivalent-of-sigalrm

Answer (score 17):

You can check whether process is alive after you tried to join it. Don't forget to set timeout otherwise it'll wait until job is finished.

Here is simple example for you

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def task():
    import time
    time.sleep(5)

procs = []

for x in range(2):
    proc = Process(target=task)
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

time.sleep(2)

for proc in procs:
    proc.join(timeout=0)
    if proc.is_alive():
        print "Job is not finished!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Pipe and messages

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import numpy as np

caller, worker = Pipe()

val1 = ['der', 'die', 'das']

def worker_function(info):
    print (info.recv())
    for i in range(10):
        print (val1[np.random.choice(3, 1)[0]])

    info.send(['job finished'])
    info.close()

def request(data):  

    caller.send(data)
    task = Process(target=worker_function, args=(worker,))
    
    if not task.is_alive():
        print ("task is requested")
        task.start()

    if caller.recv() == ['job finished']:
        task.join()
        print ("finished")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {'input': 'here'}
    request(data)
```